# Error connection pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I add a server and there are Error like this [image]

I use pgadmin4

How I can Fix this?

Comment: Is your Postgres database server enabled remote access?

Comment: I dont know, how to check it?

Comment: Ok, I will post the detail steps in a separated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check if the server is listening.
Use the following command on your server:

```
netstat -nlt|grep :5432
```

---

If it's ok, SSH (or whatever method you use to access the server) to your server and view the file:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

Find the line start with:

```
listen_addresses=
```

If the value after "=" is 'localhost', it means that you cannot connect from outside. To be able to do so, change it to:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

Now you will be able to connect from anywhere, outside from the server itself. And, don't forget to restart you DBMS and check if it works.

---

Ah. One more thing, you may also need to give your user access rights to your database as well.

Open the file:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

And add:

```
host all all * md5
```

You also need to restart you DBMS to fire up changes.

---

P/s: You should enable SSL.

Comment: How to SSH to the server? Sorry newbie here, I use windows 10

Comment: SSH is an option. You can ssh or use whatever method you use to access the server.

Comment: how to access SSH server in Heroku?

Comment: "No app specified"

Comment: Cd to your local app's folder. Run the command, its result's something close to ssh: heroku run bash

Comment: why i can find /postgresql directory?

Comment: Which OS are your server using? Try googling pg_hba.conf "[your-os-name]" (ex: pg_hba.conf ubuntu)

Comment: The above suggestions won't work for a database on Heroku. Heroku Postgres instances do not run on dynos therefore Heroku Exec cannot be used to SSH into them. For Heroku databases, it's more likely that PGAdmin or similar needs to be configured to use SSL for the connection https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/852